# Where has Luke Skywalker been?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker

Is there any info out about where Luke has been since the destruction of the second Death Star?

I have read the *Aftermath* trilogy, but there is no info in these stories as previously stated in another question.

In *Bloodline* he is ambiguously out training Ben Solo, but no real details about what's been going on with him.

Any evidence on what he has been up to?

Comment: What did that deadbeat liar Obi-won Kenobi do for 20 years on Tatooine? Jedi are very poor at dealing with defeat, they just completely shut down for literally decades.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be answered at present. Where Luke Skywalker has been is pretty implicitly going to be answered in the forthcoming The Last Jedi(Episode XIII). Good luck finding canon spoilers for that

Comment: I recall reading something from the Aftermath author that Luke was not allowed to be included, which suggests there is something going on in his storyline but can't be told yet

Comment: What about this question is attracting "primarily opinion-based" closed votes? Are people abusing the future works policy again? If the answer is "No, there's no evidence right now" that's not an opinion.

Comment: [Why was this question closed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/why-was-this-question-about-luke-skywalker-closed)

Comment: Where _hasn’t_ he been!! (Answer: almost everywhere. Where _has_ he been? [Skellig Michael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellig_Michael).)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the [Star Wars Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker):

After the fall of the Empire, Luke founded a new Jedi temple in an attempt to rebuild the Jedi Order. However, he was betrayed by his apprentice and nephew Ben Solo, the man who would become Kylo Ren, who killed the rest of Luke's Padawans and joined the dark side under the mysterious Snoke. Blaming himself, Luke disappeared and withdrew from the galaxy, going on a quest to find the first Jedi Temple. Years later, Luke was found by the Force-sensitive scavenger Rey, who followed a map to him left in fragments with R2-D2 and Lor San Tekka.

The above information is given to us by Han Solo in Episode VII, as can be seen in the following quotes from the [Episode VII transcript](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html):

> HAN: This map's not complete. It's just a piece. Ever since Luke disappeared, people have been looking for him.
>
> REY: Why'd he leave?
>
> HAN: He was training a new generation of Jedi. One boy, an apprentice turned against him, destroyed it all. Luke felt responsible... He walked away from everything.
>
> FINN: Do you know what happened to him?
>
> HAN: There're a lot of rumors. Stories. The people who knew him the best think he went looking for the first Jedi temple.
>
> REY: The Jedi were real?
>
> HAN: I used to wonder that myself. Thought it was a bunch of mumbo-jumbo -- magical power holding together good, evil, the dark side and the light. 'Crazy thing is, it's true. The Force, the Jedi, all of it. It's all true.

Comment: I don't think anything official will come up based on what I'm hearing. Since this is as comprehensive an answer as I've seen I will mark it answered. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't add my own answer because the question was put on hold, and also because your amswer is perfectly fine, so I added in quotes from the Episode VII transcript to back your answer up.

Comment: Really don't know how this got closed as "Opinion-Based", there is no opinion, we get the facts straight from Han Solo himself. There's a good chance this question will get more complete answers as more movies come out.

Comment: Of course we have learned now that Han was a bit unreliable or misinformed in the details related to the fall of Luke's new temple.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like when this book is released later this year it may answer my question. This was posted on UnboundWorlds:

[image]
The Legends of Luke Skywalker (10/31)
by Ken Liu

Details are scarce on this Journey to Star Wars: The Last Jedi novel. Liu, who you probably know as the author of The Grace of Kings, announced the book on his blog a few days ago. Given the degree of secrecy surrounding the title, I’m guessing that we might learn a little more about what the great Jedi Master was up during his self-imposed exile. Honestly, though, I don’t know any more about it than you do.

[Star Wars books at UnboundWorlds](http://www.unboundworlds.com/2017/04/heres-star-wars-books-fall-2017/?cdi=49C5B8A12B804DB3E0534FD66B0AF509&ref=PRH2028E2388CC9).

Comment: Note that this is at best a pointer to an answer, not an answer in and of itself.